# Animation with Timer is stopped when play sounds with AVAudioPlayer (AVFoundation) in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

When ViewController call the method that play sound effects, the animation with using a Timer stops for a moment (the sound is played normally).
In this case, when you touch the leaves image, the sound (tap.mp3) is played normally but leaves animation is stopped for a moment.

Why does the animation stop? How can I solve it?

```
//ViewController
//...

func startFalling(){

    // leaves
    leavesView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 70))
    leavesView.image = UIImage(named:"leaves_image")!
    self.addSubview(leavesView)

    fallingLeavesTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: TimeInterval(0.01), target: self, selector: #selector(updatePositionY(timer:)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

}

@objc func updatePositionY(timer: Timer){
    leavesView.frame.origin.y += 1
}

func touchedLeaves(){

    self.soundManager.playSE(se: "tap")

}

import Foundation
import AVFoundation

class SoundManager {

    var sePlayer: AVAudioPlayer!

    init() {
    }

    func playSE(se: String) {

        let audioFileURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: se, withExtension: "mp3")

        do {
            try sePlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: audioFileURL!)
        } catch let error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }

        sePlayer?.play()

    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try to call `sePlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: audioFileURL!)` on background queue and after that call `sePlayer?.play()` on main queue?

Comment: No I didn't. I'm sorry I haven't thought about background queue and main queue...How can I do them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think problem is because `AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: audioFileURL!)` blocked UI and it makes animation delay for a moment

To fix it, you can try to create `AVAudioPlayer` on background queue and after that play on main queue

```
func playSE(se: String) {
  DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
    let audioFileURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: se, withExtension: "mp3")

    do {
      try sePlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: audioFileURL!)
    } catch let error {
      print(error.localizedDescription)
    }

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
      sePlayer?.play()
    }
  }
}
```